# Is it possible to edit and/or remove labels in Microsoft OneNote in bulk?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, list, label, microsoft-onenote-2016, bulk

I would like to find the list of all the labels I have in Microsoft OneNote 2016 right now, and replace it with a list of new ones.

Is that possible?

I don't mind just deleting the current list in bulk and adding the new labels manually, one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

No, I am quite sure you cannot do this. I am using Microsoft One Note 2016 here.

If you were successful in deleting all your labels, I think all the pages would merge together.

Perhaps now is the time to merge pages into fewer labels and then make new labels as needed.

Before you start working, make sure you have a good backup of One Note files.